# Is there any scenario whereby type of join affects the sign of output (opposite sign)

Tags: sql

I have study a term class in sql. Not entirely a beginner but can't help to be curious if there is a special scenario whereby the sign of the output is flipped due to the type of join we used.

Table A

```
Fruit | Price
apple | $0.5
Kiwi  | $2.0
Pear  | $1.5
```

Table B (some other table use for joining)

Result:

```
Fruit | Price
apple | - $0.5
Kiwi  | - $2.0
Pear  | - $1.5
Grape | $5.0
Lemon | $3.0
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please provide some sample data to illustrate what you mean.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Sorry for the sample data. In this case, there is no sample data, I am just wondering under what scenario will this unfavorable result be achieve.

Comment: @PCiah can you add the data from table b in this sample? where are "Grape" and "Lemon" coming from?

Comment: A join will never influence the actual value stored in the table's column

Answer (score 0):

There is some serious confusion here. `JOIN` is an operator that works on tables (or subqueries or result sets) in SQL. The result from any `JOIN` is simply the set of columns in the referenced tables. With one small exception -- which I will explain -- `JOIN`s do not alter the values of the columns. It simply returns columns from two or more table references.

The one exception is that outer joins can produce `NULL` values. That does not actually *change* the value. It simply represents that the "matching" row does not exist.